# How can I use Apache to reverse proxy a dynamic url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want a user to be able to load a url in their browser, but not get redirected:

```
http://example.com/abc/{var1}/{var2}/def
```

I want the example.com apache 2.2 server to take that request, and "invisibly" and without redirect reverse proxy it to:

```
http://other.example.com/abc/{var1}/{var2}/def
```

I have spent hours trying different combinations of RewriteRule, ProxyPass, ProxyPassMatch, and ProxyPassReverse, all to no avail.  Here is my current attempt, which seems to do a redirect to /test instead of an invisible proxy.

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/def/?$ /test/abc/$1/$2/def [P]
ProxyPass /test http://other.example.com/ 
ProxyPassReverse /test http://other.example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

The [P] flag already has the functionality of `ProxyPass`. You only need to add a `ProxyPassReverse`. Also, if you want to proxy, you must use a full url as the second operand of `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/def/?$ http://other.example.com/abc/$1/$2/def [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://other.example.com/
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that configuration produces an infinite 301 redirect loop.  If I take out the ProxyPassReverse it redirects to the other server in the browser URL.  Thoughts?

Comment: Post your logs (access log and rewrite log with rewriteloglevel 9).

Comment: @Artefacto will tthe parameters get passed to the URL? If not, what's the way to pass these params i.e `$1 & $2`